# How to check the Nvidia CUDA core usage in real time?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I wonder if there are any tools for monitoring the Nvidia GPU CUDA core usage in real time?

Similar to `$watch nvidia-smi` to check the GPU memory usage.

Thanks.